# Uncertainty principle with a multiplier

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Let me take the unitary Fourier transform $\mathcal F$ on the real line $\mathbb R$ for simplicity - I know the uncertainty principle says that if $\lVert f \rVert_2 = \lVert \hat{f} \rVert_2 = 1$ then there is a lower bound on $\lVert x f \rVert_2 \lVert \xi \hat{f} \rVert_2$ and I can prove it using properties of the Fourier transform.

I'm wondering if there is an analogue of the uncertainty principle where $\lVert x f \rVert_2 \lVert \xi \hat{f} \rVert_2$ is replaced by $\lVert M(x) f \rVert_2 \lVert M(\xi) \hat{f} \rVert_2$ for some multiplication operator $M(x)$ which we might as well for simplicity assume is nonnegative. (The basic examples I have in mind are $M(x) = x^p$ for some power $p$, or $M(x) = e^x$.) Is there a lower bound on this quantity?

My intuition is yes since $f$ can't be localised near where $M$ is small (so that $\lVert M(x)f \rVert_2$ is small without $\hat{f}$ being "spread out" by the uncertainty principle, but at the same time I can't find a generalisation elsewhere and I'm not sure how to generalise the proof to an arbitrary multiplier $M$.

Comment: Perhaps the following fact might be a starting point of investigation: If $A$ and $B$ are two self-adjoint operators, then the uncertainty relation tells that $$\|Af\|_2 \|Bf\|_2 \geq \left| \frac{1}{2i} \langle f, [A,B]f \rangle \right| ,$$ where $[A, B]=AB-BA$ is the commutator.

Comment: I agree, then you just have to estimate $[M(x),M(i\nabla)]$, which you can do using Leibniz rule when $M(x) = x^n$ with $n$ an integer, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula when $M(x) = e^x$